# How to pipe Systemd service standard output from ExecStart to shell, ex. bash?

Tags: linux, bash, service, sh, systemd

I have a Systemd service that starts the process of output which I need to execute as a normal Bash script

```
[Unit]
Description=Example app

[Service]
Type=simple
PIDFile=/var/run/app.pid
Sockets=app.socket
StandardInput=fd:app.socket
#StandardOutput=fd:sh
StandardError=journal
ExecStart=/usr/bin/app -a | sh # 

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Instead of execution, the output of the application falls into the log.

Tell me how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can't really pipe stuff in `ExecStart`, but you can do:

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/app -a | sh '
```